# How to make a print dialog with preview for printing an image file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a mac cocoa image editing application. I would like to add print image functionality to my application. I basically always have a jpg/png file with me. Whenever the user goes to File -> Print menu I would like to give user a dialog with print options/settings to print this jpg/png file. I would like the print dialog to be customized for image printing such as one we get when printing an image from Preview application.

I don't want to use something like the following because this will give a plain not very customizable print dialog:

```
[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:viewToPrint printInfo:[self.document printInfo]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can put everything inside a NSView and then use the `print` method. This method will print everything that's inside the view (including subviews). Now for the customizable printing you can make something like: User clicks a button labeled "print", it makes your custom made dialog appear where the user can choose options such as, show exemple date (which is in a subview, of the view that's going to be printed), you store those options and them when the user clicks the print at your dialog, you can remove the subview he didn't wanted to show. And after its printed, show it again. There's also other methods for printing views here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
NSImage *pic =  [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"/Users/Anne/Desktop/Sample.png"];
NSRect picRect = NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, pic.size.width, pic.size.height));
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:picRect];
[imageView setImage:pic];
NSPrintOperation * picPrint = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:imageView printInfo:printInfo];
[picPrint setCanSpawnSeparateThread:YES];
[picPrint runOperation];
```

Comment: It will be better if you can explain what the code does.