# Check whether an application exists on Mac from cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How can I check from my cocoa Mac application whether an application (for example: Preview or iPhoto) exists on Mac?

I basically want to give the user an option to open an image using Preview, iPhoto but before doing that I would like to check whether these applications are present on the user's Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking for specific hard-coded applications, it'd be better to [get a list of all applications that can handle the type of document you'll be passing to them](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType). That way, if the user has installed, say, [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/), it'll automatically show up without your having to add it to your hard-coded list.

There is also [a way to do what you specifically asked for](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSFindApplicationForInfo), but that is an inferior way to do what you really want to do, which is show the user all of their applications that can open the document.

Comment: Peter, thank you for the answer. The reason I am looking for Preview app specifically is that in my image editing application I always have a jpg/png/tiff file that represents the user document. Now, instead of implementing a print dialog from scratch I would like to show user a dialog with the message that they can print the image using Preview app and provide a button in this dialog to open the image in Preview app. I had asked a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452144/print-dialog-for-printing-an-image-file-in-cocoa-mac-application Can you suggest a better way

Comment: @AmaltasCoder: The better way is your original plan. I have no idea how to implement it, but I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be possible. Check the WWDC 2010 and 2011 sessions; one of them might cover it.

Comment: Is it possible somehow that when I open the image in Preview app I also give the Preview application a print command from my application so that the print dialog in Preview is also opened. The same as the effect of cmd+p on Preview. I asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538345/print-using-preview-application-on-mac-from-cocoa-application